# How to pass a pointer to an element of a two-dimensional array to a function?

Tags: c, algorithm

I have started reading [*Introduction to Algorithms*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms), by Cormen, and have encountered problems with Strassen's algorithm (chapter 4.2):

> Sǫᴜᴀʀᴇ-Mᴀᴛʀɪx-Mᴜʟᴛɪᴘʟʏ-Rᴇᴄᴜʀsɪᴠᴇ(, )
>   1    = .
>   2   let  be a new  ×  matrix
>   3   **if**  == 1
>   4           <sub>11</sub> = <sub>11</sub> ⋅ <sub>11</sub>
>   5   **else** partition , , and  as in equations (4.9)
>   6           <sub>11</sub> = Sǫᴜᴀʀᴇ-Mᴀᴛʀɪx-Mᴜʟᴛɪᴘʟʏ-Rᴇᴄᴜʀsɪᴠᴇ(<sub>11</sub>, <sub>11</sub>)
>                      + Sǫᴜᴀʀᴇ-Mᴀᴛʀɪx-Mᴜʟᴛɪᴘʟʏ-Rᴇᴄᴜʀsɪᴠᴇ(<sub>12</sub>, <sub>21</sub>)
>   7           <sub>12</sub> = Sǫᴜᴀʀᴇ-Mᴀᴛʀɪx-Mᴜʟᴛɪᴘʟʏ-Rᴇᴄᴜʀsɪᴠᴇ(<sub>11</sub>, <sub>12</sub>)
>                      + Sǫᴜᴀʀᴇ-Mᴀᴛʀɪx-Mᴜʟᴛɪᴘʟʏ-Rᴇᴄᴜʀsɪᴠᴇ(<sub>12</sub>, <sub>22</sub>)
>   8           <sub>21</sub> = Sǫᴜᴀʀᴇ-Mᴀᴛʀɪx-Mᴜʟᴛɪᴘʟʏ-Rᴇᴄᴜʀsɪᴠᴇ(<sub>21</sub>, <sub>11</sub>)
>                      + Sǫᴜᴀʀᴇ-Mᴀᴛʀɪx-Mᴜʟᴛɪᴘʟʏ-Rᴇᴄᴜʀsɪᴠᴇ(<sub>22</sub>, <sub>21</sub>)
>   9           <sub>22</sub> = Sǫᴜᴀʀᴇ-Mᴀᴛʀɪx-Mᴜʟᴛɪᴘʟʏ-Rᴇᴄᴜʀsɪᴠᴇ(<sub>21</sub>, <sub>12</sub>)
>                      + Sǫᴜᴀʀᴇ-Mᴀᴛʀɪx-Mᴜʟᴛɪᴘʟʏ-Rᴇᴄᴜʀsɪᴠᴇ(<sub>22</sub>, <sub>22</sub>)
> 10   **return**

I decided to implement the algorithm function like this:

```
int ** square_matrix_multiply_recursive (int ** arr_a, int ** arr_b, int ** arr_c, int N);
```

And during the recursive call of this function I need to pass a pointer to the matrix element. I don't know how.

The actual code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE_STRING_A 2
#define SIZE_STRING_B 2
#define SIZE_COLUMN_A 2
#define SIZE_COLUMN_B 2

int ** square_matrix_multiply_recursive (int ** arr_a, int ** arr_b, int ** arr_c, int N);

int main (void)
{
    int ** arr_a;
    arr_a = (int**) calloc (SIZE_STRING_A, sizeof (int*));
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_STRING_A; i++)
        arr_a [i] = (int*) calloc (SIZE_COLUMN_A, sizeof (int));
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_STRING_A; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE_COLUMN_A; j++)
            arr_a [i] [j] = i + j;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_STRING_A; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE_COLUMN_B; j++)
            printf ("%d ", arr_a [i] [j]);
        printf ("\n");
    }
    
    int ** arr_b;
    arr_b = (int**) calloc (SIZE_STRING_B, sizeof (int*));
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_STRING_B; i++)
        arr_b [i] = (int*) calloc (SIZE_COLUMN_B, sizeof (int));
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_STRING_B; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE_COLUMN_B; j++)
            arr_b [i] [j] = i + j;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_STRING_A; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE_COLUMN_B; j++)
            printf ("%d ", arr_b [i] [j]);
        printf ("\n");
    }
    
    int ** arr_c;
    arr_c = (int**) calloc (SIZE_STRING_A, sizeof (int*));
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_STRING_B; i++)
        arr_c [i] = (int*) calloc (SIZE_COLUMN_B, sizeof (int));

    square_matrix_multiply_recursive (arr_a, arr_b, arr_c, 2);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_STRING_A; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE_COLUMN_B; j++)
            printf ("%d ", arr_c [i] [j]);
        printf ("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}


int ** square_matrix_multiply_recursive (int ** arr_a, int ** arr_b, int ** arr_c, int N)
{
    if (N == 1)
    {
        (**arr_c) = (**arr_b) * (**arr_a);
        return arr_c;
    }
    else 
    {
        arr_c [0] [0] = (**square_matrix_multiply_recursive (/*arr_a [0] [0]*/, /*arr_b [0] [0]*/, /*arr_c [0] [0]*/, N / 2)) + (**square_matrix_multiply_recursive (/*arr_a [0] [1]*/, /*arr_b [1] [0]*/, /*arr_c [0] [0]*/, N / 2));
        
    }
    return arr_c;
}
```

There are many problems in the code (this is a test version), but the fatal one is passing a pointer to a matrix element.

Comment: So what is the problem? Does it not compile? Or does it compile but does not work? Once your code has lots of `int **` in it, you've probably made a bad design decision.

Comment: @lexa removing the unnecessary casts would improve the look of code.  Consider `int ** arr_a; arr_a = (int**) calloc (SIZE_STRING_A, sizeof (int*))` --> `int ** arr_a = calloc(SIZE_STRING_A, sizeof *arr_a)` for example.

Comment: Does this compile cleanly with warnings enabled? My compiler does not like it. e.g. this: `arr_c [0] [0] = (**square_matrix_multiply_recursive (/*arr_a [0] [0]*/, /*arr_b [0] [0]*/, /*arr_c [0] [0]*/, N / 2)) + (**square_matrix_multiply_recursive (/*arr_a [0] [1]*/, /*arr_b [1] [0]*/, /*arr_c [0] [0]*/, N / 2));` which looks like something from the obfuscated C contest.

Comment: Strassen’s algorithm is for seeking performance, and you should not use pointers-to-pointers for high performance. Use pointers to arrays.

Comment: Unrelated, but the image is not representing Strassen's algorithm, as the latter reduces the number of multiplications by creating different matrices. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm#Algorithm) and the  matrices listed there.

Comment: But your code is not attempting much other than assigning to `arr_c [0] [0]`. And the place where the recursion occurs has lots of inline comments and syntax errors. I would start by fixing the syntax errors.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 2):

As your code cannot compile as it stands, and it only attempts to assign to `arr_c[0][0]`, there is much left to do. As to the question, *"how to pass a pointer to a matrix element"*, the answer is that you shouldn't. Your matrix elements are integers, and they are not supposed to be pointers.

In fact, it is probably more readable to implement this without explicit pointers since you can use array notation throughout. I would also suggest to:

- avoid code repetition (like the print logic, the matrix allocation logic, ...)
- create more functions (with smaller bodies) that each deal with specific aspects

There are many ways to do this, here is just one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    size_t row;
    size_t col;
} pos;

void print_square_matrix(size_t n, int matrix[][n]) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

// Add a number of rows and columns to a position and return it
pos offset(pos anchor, size_t add_row, size_t add_col) {
    anchor.row += add_row;
    anchor.col += add_col;
    return anchor;
}

void square_matrix_multiply_recursive(size_t n, size_t size, 
                                      int a[][n], pos apos, 
                                      int b[][n], pos bpos, 
                                      int c[][n], pos cpos);

void multiply_and_add(size_t n, size_t size, 
                      int a[][n], pos apos1, pos apos2,
                      int b[][n], pos bpos1, pos bpos2, 
                      int c[][n], pos cpos) {
    square_matrix_multiply_recursive(n, size, a, apos1, b, bpos1, c, cpos);
    square_matrix_multiply_recursive(n, size, a, apos2, b, bpos2, c, cpos);
}

void square_matrix_multiply_recursive(size_t n, size_t size, 
                                      int a[][n], pos apos, 
                                      int b[][n], pos bpos, 
                                      int c[][n], pos cpos) {
    if (size == 1) {
        // Use += to accumulate (two) results
        c[cpos.row][cpos.col] += a[apos.row][apos.col] * b[bpos.row][bpos.col];
    } else {
        size /= 2;
        for (size_t row = 0; row <= size; row += size) {
            for (size_t col = 0; col <= size; col += size) {
                multiply_and_add(n, size, 
                    a, offset(apos, row, 0), offset(apos, row, size), 
                    b, offset(bpos, 0, col), offset(bpos, size, col),
                    c, offset(cpos, row, col));
            }
        }
    }
}

void square_matrix_multiply(size_t n, int a[][n], int b[][n], int c[][n]) {
    square_matrix_multiply_recursive(n, n, a, (pos) {0}, b, (pos) {0}, c, (pos) {0});
}

// N must be a power of 2
#define N 4

int main (void)
{
    // Example input:
    int arr_a[N][N] = {{ 0,  2, -1,  3}, 
                       { 2,  1,  0, -4},
                       {-1, -3,  2,  1},
                       { 3,  1, -2,  2}};
    int arr_b[N][N] = {{ 5,  2, -1,  2}, 
                       {-3, -3,  2,  0},
                       { 1,  1, -3,  0},
                       { 2, -2, -4,  3}};
    // Calculate the product
    int arr_c[N][N] = {0}; // Initialize with all zeroes (important)
    square_matrix_multiply(N, arr_a, arr_b, arr_c);
    // Output results
    print_square_matrix(N, arr_a);
    print_square_matrix(N, arr_b);
    print_square_matrix(N, arr_c);
    return 0;
}
```

This example run has the following output:

```
0 2 -1 3 
2 1 0 -4 
-1 -3 2 1 
3 1 -2 2 

5 2 -1 2 
-3 -3 2 0 
1 1 -3 0 
2 -2 -4 3 

-1 -13 -5 9 
-1 9 16 -8 
8 7 -15 1 
14 -3 -3 12
```

Finally, be aware that this does not fully implement Strassen's algorithm: the divide and conquer approach is the same, but that algorithm applies a different set of matrix operations so to save on the number of them. See the use of the  matrices in the Wikipedia article on [Strassen's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm#Algorithm).